# MS Word Chinese version: Font-changing

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word, resize

Here is the macro code that is meant to convert Latin letters into Cyrillic:

```
Sub code()
'

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "jio"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1105)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "zh"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1078)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ja"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1103)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ju"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1102)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "aj"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1072) & ChrW(1081)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ej"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1077) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ij"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1080) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "oj"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1086) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "uj"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1091) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ey"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1101)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "yj"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1099) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ju"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1102)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ja"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1103)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(1105) & "j"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1105) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(1101) & "j"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1101) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(1102) & "j"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1102) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(1103) & "j"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1103) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "jj"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1098)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "q"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1098)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " j"
        .Replacement.Text = " " & ChrW(1081)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "j"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1100)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "b"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1073)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "v"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1074)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "g"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1075)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "d"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1076)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "z"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1079)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "k"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1082)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "l"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1083)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "m"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1084)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "n"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1085)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "p"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1087)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "r"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1088)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "t"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1090)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "f"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1092)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "x"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1093)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "ch"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1095)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "sh"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1096)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "s"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1089)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "c"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1094)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "w"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1097)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "y"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1099)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "e"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1077)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "i"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1080)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "u"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1091)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ChrW(1054) & ChrW(1049)
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(1086) & ChrW(1081)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " " & ChrW(1071)
        .Replacement.Text = " " & ChrW(1103)
      .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    ' AllToGeorgia12:
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"


End Sub
```

The last three executable lines of this code are meant to change the font type to "Georgia" font size 12:

```
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Font.Size = 12
Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"
```

It's strange, but the last line doesn't seem to change the font type to "Georgia". Or even if it does, it changes only a few letters in the text, but not the whole text.

For example, if I want to convert these Latin letters into Cyrillic:

```
eyto budet russkij tekst
```

I get the following line in Ciryllic:

```
это будет русский текст
```

but only the third letter in it, letter "o", becomes "Georgian".

Here is what I have before running the macro:

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pics/start_4.jpg))</sub>

and here is what I get as a result:

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pics/end_4.jpg))</sub>

Here only the third letter "o" is of **Georgia** font type, all the other letters are of some strange **MS Mincho** font type, which is never even mentioned in my code.

So, it seems that the very last line in the code

```
Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"
```

doesn't work at all. I don't know why.

It's interesting that whenever I run the last three lines separately as a macro:

```
Sub AllToGeorgia12()

    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"


End Sub
```

everything works fine. But when I embed those three lines in the end of my code, the last line doesn't seem to work.

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776263/msword-change-font-and-font-size) I was suggested to do the debugging. So when I set up a break point on the first of those three lines and then proceed executing them manually, everything works fine. However, when I try to run the whole macro again, the last line doesn't do its job.

Does anybody know what the problem here could be? Could it be related to the fact that I am using Chinese version of MS Word (I am currently in Taiwan)? My version is MS Word 2003.

Comment: I tried it in Office Word 2007 (saved in 97-2003 format) and I can't reproduce (not saying it's not happening). Have you tried completely starting a new file, copying in only the VBA plaintext, and trying again?

Comment: @Jred Farrish: "Have you tried completely starting a new file, copying in only the VBA plaintext, and trying again?" - I don't know how to do it. Don't even know what VBA plaintext is. Can you, please, direct me here?

Comment: @Jred Farrish: Did you mean I had to copy the code from this page (this my question page on StackOverflow) and create another macro by pasting the copied code in the code editor window? If yes, then I did it just now. I named this new macro "code2". However, when I tried running it I achieved just the same results - those shown on my second screen shot above.

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Word 2010 as well.

Comment: Øystein: "Unable to reproduce on Word 2010 as well" - Do you mean you couldn't achieve the results that I am also trying to achieve or you didn't even get what is shown on my second screen shot here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **directly** related to the font and language: Georgia and 中文. Georgia does not support Chinese characters and your default language Chinese, so it defaults the font a character set that does support it (probably SimSun or MS Mincho). SimSun *does* support Cyrillic, except for one character (o), so the total selection is listed as blank in the font list (because you have mixed fonts). If you change the language of the selection to Russian, you will see that it does display "Georgia". So at end of your macro you could put:

```
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"
    Selection.LanguageID = wdRussian
```

And then it would work. I've tested on:

- Word 2003 Chinese Taiwan (中文（繁體）), Windows Vista
- Word 2010 Chinese P.R.C. (中文（简体）), Windows XP

and the result is the same - the font becomes Georgia. If you just change the language off of Chinese Taiwan to Russian or English for the letters/characters you are converting, you'll get the right font listed.

Also, I've tried to simplify your code as it was just too long and had stuff in there that wasn't needed:

```
Sub ReplaceText(Text As String, ReplacementText As String)
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Text
        .Replacement.Text = ReplacementText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchByte = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
Sub Code()
    ReplaceText "jio", ChrW(1105)
    ReplaceText "zh", ChrW(1078)
    ReplaceText "ja", ChrW(1103)
    ReplaceText "ju", ChrW(1102)
    ReplaceText "aj", ChrW(1072) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "ej", ChrW(1077) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "ij", ChrW(1080) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "oj", ChrW(1086) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "uj", ChrW(1091) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "ey", ChrW(1101)
    ReplaceText "yj", ChrW(1099) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "ju", ChrW(1102)
    ReplaceText "ja", ChrW(1103)
    ReplaceText ChrW(1105) & "j", ChrW(1105) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText ChrW(1101) & "j", ChrW(1101) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText ChrW(1102) & "j", ChrW(1102) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText ChrW(1103) & "j", ChrW(1103) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "jj", ChrW(1098)
    ReplaceText "q", ChrW(1098)
    ReplaceText " j", " " & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText "j", ChrW(1100)
    ReplaceText "b", ChrW(1073)
    ReplaceText "v", ChrW(1074)
    ReplaceText "g", ChrW(1075)
    ReplaceText "d", ChrW(1076)
    ReplaceText "z", ChrW(1079)
    ReplaceText "k", ChrW(1082)
    ReplaceText "l", ChrW(1083)
    ReplaceText "m", ChrW(1084)
    ReplaceText "n", ChrW(1085)
    ReplaceText "p", ChrW(1087)
    ReplaceText "r", ChrW(1088)
    ReplaceText "t", ChrW(1090)
    ReplaceText "f", ChrW(1092)
    ReplaceText "x", ChrW(1093)
    ReplaceText "ch", ChrW(1095)
    ReplaceText "sh", ChrW(1096)
    ReplaceText "s", ChrW(1089)
    ReplaceText "c", ChrW(1094)
    ReplaceText "w", ChrW(1097)
    ReplaceText "y", ChrW(1099)
    ReplaceText "e", ChrW(1077)
    ReplaceText "i", ChrW(1080)
    ReplaceText "u", ChrW(1091)
    ReplaceText ChrW(1054) & ChrW(1049), ChrW(1086) & ChrW(1081)
    ReplaceText " " & ChrW(1071), " " & ChrW(1103)

    ' AllToGeorgia12:
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"
    Selection.LanguageID = wdRussian

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and willingness to help. i don't know why, but even when I add that line to my code (`Selection.LanguageID = wdRussian`) right above the `End Sub` line - just like you said - I still get the same result. My MSWord version is 2003 and I am using XP - do you have any way of testing it on XP?

Comment: Thank you also for simplifying my code, but when I paste it in the macro editor window it splits into two codes because there two `Sub` and `End Sub` pairs in it, so I simply can't use it as one piece of code. Am I doing anything wrong here? I'll be away for two days so i won't be able to reply soon during these two days. Anyway, you already have the bounty! Thanks for trying to help me here.

Comment: @brillant: you can revert to your old code if you just need all of it in one routine, but the simplification allows you to just press run (or F5) when you have your cursor placed inside the `Code` routine. I since have tested the code on 2003 (Chinese Traditional) and XP and it works as well with the addition of `Selection.LanguageID = wdRussian`.

Comment: "I since have tested the code on 2003 (Chinese Traditional) and XP and it works as well" - Okay, then it's a problem with my computer. So I will ask about it on Super User. Thank you again, Otaku, for your time and for your great help.